# Tradução dos botões de edições sugeridas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Já alguém tinha reparado que isto está por traduzir?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugestão:

Improve Edit    => Melhorar Edição
Reject and Edit => Rejeitar e Editar

Comment: É que essas strings são novas, antes o botão era só editar, e depois você marcava no checkbox se a edição tinha sido útil ou não. De qualquer forma, a questão é válida, e as strings novas precisam ser traduzidas. +1 (mas eu prefiro "Aprovar e Melhorar" e "Rejeitar e Melhorar", ou coisa do tipo, para ficar evidente que o 1o botão aceita o edit original)

Comment: Gostei da tua sugestão @Bacco +1

Comment: @Bacco my Portuguese is nil, but: "Aprovar e Melhorar" seems to suggest "Approve and Improve" - that isn't quite what we are trying to convey via "Improve Edit". I can add the overrides to the system, but: some kind of consensus on appropriate text would be good. Otherwise, it'll sit and wait for the 3rd-party translators to supply text.

Comment: @MarcGravell indeed. Literally it would be "Melhorar Edição" and "Rejeitar e Editar" in portuguese, as Jorge B. wrote (also, we usually uppercase only the first letter). Just a side note: IMHO even the english version could be more clear that "Improve edit" means aproving it first (probably with better wording than mine, of course).

Comment: @MarcGravell just for clarifying: the original translation, as posted by Jorge B., is accurate. My comment was about the whole idea, not the translation itself. You can use "Melhorar Edição" and "Rejeitar e Editar" without any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Pronto. Mas fiz uma pequena alteração, em nome da brevidade:

> Improve Edit => Melhorar
>   Reject and Edit => Rejeitar e Editar

Não vejo por que deixar "edição" explícito, se você sabe que esta avaliando edições.