# Postar no meta pedidos de tradução para atualizações nos sites

Tags: novo-recurso, tradução, internacionalização

Toda vez que forem atualizar ou inserir algum texto em outro site da rede fazer postagem no meta pedindo tradução.

Não é novidade que isso ocorre quando atualizam os sites principais:

[Tradução da rejeição na análise de edições](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2100/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-rejei%C3%A7%C3%A3o-na-an%C3%A1lise-de-edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

[Tradução dos botões de edições sugeridas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1942/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dos-bot%C3%B5es-de-edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-sugeridas)

Acho que houveram em mais ocassiões tal ocorrido, mas não pretendo procurá-las.

Comment: Não entendi, você está propondo uma postagem automática no meta?

Comment: Isso, ou que quando as atualizações forem feitas que os programadores postem o que foi auterado e peça a tradução equivalente para tal conteúdo.

Comment: Se for tecnicamente possível, seria ótimo mesmo.